# Change C# formatting braces in VScode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, format, prettier

When working on my C# project in VScode, prettier, the extension, doesnt apply the same formatting that it uses in other languages which I prefer. It doesn't format my code which is where I want my braces to be on the same line as my function statements like below

```cs
void Start() {
    DefaultLayer = gameObject.layer;
}
```

however my code looks like this

```cs
void Start()
{
    DefaultLayer = gameObject.layer;
}
```

and wont change by adding anything like an omnisharp.json file in the root or modifying anything? How can I make my braces format as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Go to tools>options>text editor>C#>tabs in the indenting scope select block.